# Recurring events on resource calendars using Google Calendar API and python

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

Im writing a python script with the Admin directory and Google Calendar API's. The goal is to get a list of recurring events from all the resource calendars on the Google workspace domain, then modify the events recurrences to end after 90 days. I have the script working to pull all the resource calendar email addresses, add them to a list and then pull out the events from all the 7 resource calendars. I cant seem to find a way to filter and get just the recurring events, my script gets single events and recurring events. I've tried to use **event['recurringEventId']** but it errors out. Is there a way to filter the results from events to just recurring?

Code below:

```
import datetime
import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

#API scopes If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly', 
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events', 
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.resource.calendar']

#Create empty list to hold resource calendar emails
cal_list = []
event_list = []

#Authorise app to access Google account
creds = None
# The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.
if os.path.exists('token.json'):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())
        

"""Call directory api to list resource calendar email addresses
and add them to cal_list"""
with build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=creds) as service_admin:
    calendars = service_admin.resources().calendars().list(customer='C03r7ld3j', maxResults=40).execute()
    for calendar in calendars['items']:
        cal_list.append(calendar['resourceEmail'])
    print(cal_list)
      

service_cal = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)
#call the calendar api to pull the events from the resource calendar list
page_token = None
for el in cal_list:
    events = service_cal.events().list(calendarId=el, pageToken=page_token).execute()
    for event in events['items']:
        print(event)
    page_token = events.get('nextPageToken')
```

Answer (score 0):

`recurringEventId` is only set on the instances of the recurring events (which you only get when `singleEvents=True`, but you don't need this). But the "parent" recurring event has a `recurrence` set so that you can filter it with `if event.get("recurrence")`.

You can simplify all this with [gcsa](https://google-calendar-simple-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library:

```
from gcsa.goolge_calendar import GoogleCalendar

gc = GoogleCalendar('credentials.json')

for cl in cal_list:
    for e in gc.get_events(calendar_id=cl):
        if e.recurrence:
             e.recurrence = ... # updated recurrence
             updated_event = gc.update_event(e)
             print(updated_event)
```

For recurrence, see the [recurrence docs](https://google-calendar-simple-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recurrence.html)